# How to change a key in tree-view?

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, tree, treeview

I have a possible infinite tree-view array:

```
type Tree = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  children: Tree[];
};

const tree: Tree = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Truck',
    email: '@mail',
    children: [
      {
        id: 11,
        name: 'Car',
        email: '@mail',
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bus',
    email: '@mail',
    children: [],
  },
];
```

There are 3 things I wish to do to this array.

1. change the property key 'id' to 'userId'
2. change the id type from number to string
3. remove the email property

so the output will match this type:

```
type NewTree = {
  userId: string;
  name: string;
  children: NewTree[];
};

// output of the new tree
const newTree: NewTree = [
  {
    userId: '1',
    name: 'Truck',
    children: [
      {
        userId: '11',
        name: 'Car',
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    userId: '2',
    name: 'Bus'
    children: [],
  },
];
```

This is what I currently have

```
const restructuredTree = (tree: any[]) => {
  for (const node in tree) {
    const { id: userId, name, children } = tree[node];
    restructuredTree(children);
    tree[node] = { userId, name, children };
  }
};
```

Not sure where to do a return statement, and when I return "tree[node] = { userId, name, children };" it's only changing one level deep.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Search everything you need to modify a single object so that it fulfills your requirement. Then try to find a way to traverse through a nested object. Then combine both steps.

Comment: Will update what I have so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as well as destructuring to pull out the desired properties (id, name, children). For each object, you can map to a new object, where you set the children key to be the re-mapped version of the current `children` array by recursively re-calling your function to perform the same destructuring + mapping logic. Eventually, you'll reach an object where the children key is an empty array `[]`, and so the map callback won't be called which means that `getNewTree()` won't be called either - this acts as your base-case / termination condition that will end the recursion:

```js
const tree = [ { id: 1, name: 'Truck', email: '@mail', children: [ { id: 11, name: 'Car', email: '@mail', children: [], }, ], }, { id: 2, name: 'Bus', email: '@mail', children: [], }, ];

const getNewTree = (tree) => tree.map(({id, name, children}) => ({
  userId: String(id),
  name,
  children: getNewTree(children)
})); 
console.log(getNewTree(tree));
```